# What does it mean when I see "Re-entry is not allowed"?

Tags: java, exception, dependency-injection, guice, illegalstateexception

I'm trying to do something like this.

```
class A extends B {
    Injector injector = Guice.CreateInjector(this);
    // ......statements...
}
```

It is throwing `IllegalStateException` : Re-entry is not allowed

```
com.google.inject.internal.util.$Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:142)
    at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:55)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:223)
    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:101)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:133)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:103)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:95)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:72)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: can you please paste your config file?

Comment: Config file as in ?  sorry, I'm new to Guice.  which file do i need to paste ?

Comment: createInjector takes one or more Modules. Are A and B modules? Could you please provide a full example that makes it possible to understand what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way this would happen is if you call `Guice.createInjector()` on the **same module instance inside the `configure` method**. It *won't* happen if you call it at object construction as you do in your example. Here's code that will reproduce that stack trace.

```
class B extends AbstractModule {
    protected void configure() {
    }
}

public class A extends B {
  Injector injector;

  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    injector = Guice.createInjector(this);
  }
}

public class GuiceTest {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    A a = new A();
    Injector inj = Guice.createInjector(a);
  }
}
```

My response on how to fix it is... don't do this! There's never even remotely any reason to do this.

Until you know what you're doing, you should never call `Guice.createInjector()` more than once in your application, and that once is usually in your `Main` class or in many cases in your `static void main` method itself.. I use Guice for everything and I **still have never called it more than once in the same app**. The idea is that you build your modules, pass them into your injector, and then let Guice inject everything else for you. See: [Getting Started](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/GettingStarted)

What are you trying to do that has made you try to do this? Note: Please don't answer me by editing your question or by commenting, as these two things will [invalidate this answer.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/200235) Instead, [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) that explains what you're really trying to do, and [avoid the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/200235).